# Good implementation of a Change Calculator in C#

Tags: c#, calculator

Given an amount in ml and 3 pack sizes (20ml, 200ml and 1000ml) I'd like to calculate how many of each packs are needed to fulfill the total amount.

E.g.

```
Amount = 3210ml
1000ml = 3 packs
200ml = 1 pack
20ml = 1 pack (always round up to nearest quantity)
```

This is pretty much just like a change calculator, and I'm looking for the *right* way to do it.

**Here's my attempt**

```
public class PackSizeCalculator
{
    private const int LargePackSize = 1000;
    private const int MediumPackSize = 200;
    private const int SmallPackSize = 20;

    public int LargePacks {get; set;}
    public int MediumPacks {get; set;}
    public int SmallPacks {get; set;}

    public  PackSizeCalculator(int amount)
    {
        int remainder = amount;

        while(remainder > 0) {
            if(remainder >= LargePackSize)
            {
                LargePacks = remainder / LargePackSize;
                remainder = remainder % LargePackSize;
            }
            else if(remainder >= MediumPackSize)
            {
                MediumPacks = remainder / MediumPackSize;
                remainder = remainder % MediumPackSize;
            }
            else if(remainder > SmallPackSize)
            {
                if(remainder % SmallPackSize == 0)
                {
                    SmallPacks = (remainder / SmallPackSize);
                }
                else {
                    SmallPacks = (remainder / SmallPackSize) + 1;
                }
                remainder = 0;
            }
            else {
                SmallPacks = 1;
                remainder = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a good way to go about it or would you recommend something different?

Comment: There is no RIGHT way to do it. Your "question" sounds more like "Please do it for me". It's brain outsourcing... You are looking for an algorithm, not really a technical code/programming issue. This is might perhaps be a sign of lame laziness as you should at least present your pre-reflection/algo alternatives you thought of.

Comment: @Marko This is so trivial that there aren't any well-known programs for doing this.

Comment: You're vastly over-thinking things. You can determine each value in a single division/modulus operation; there should be no branching or looping. Also, ugh. There's no 'hate' associated with downvotes, and I don't think two counts as "lots".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
const int LARGE_PACK = 1000;
const int MEDIUM_PACK = 200;
const int SMALL_PACK = 20;

int largePacks = (int)(Amount / LARGE_PACK);
int mediumPacks = (int)((Amount % LARGE_PACK) / MEDIUM_PACK);
int smallPacks = (int)ceil(((float)((Amount % LARGE_PACK) % MEDIUM_PACK) / SMALL_PACK));
```

Comment: You're doing integer division so you don't need to cast to int (unless you are assuming Amount is not an int). Also, smallPacks isn't rounded up as per the question.

Comment: I like to make explicit casts for easier to understand code. And you are correct about the second point, I'll update it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function like this:

```
struct Change
{
    public int  Large;
    public int  Medium;
    public int  Small;
}
private Change CalculateChange(int TotalAmount)
{
    Change result;
    result.Large = TotalAmount >= 1000 ? TotalAmount / 1000 : 0;
    result.Medium = TotalAmount % 1000 >= 200 ? (TotalAmount % 1000) / 200 : 0;
    result.Small = (TotalAmount % 1000) % 200 >= 20 ? ((TotalAmount % 1000) % 200) / 20 : 0;
    return result;
}
```

At the end you will have your result of  Change struct Type.